# Authorize attribute in Area not working as desired

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem securing a newly created Area in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

Currently we have one other area with some existing controllers decorated with the "Authorize" attribute. We are using forms authentication and a login page for the users to login. When directly calling an action method for the existing area through the URL the user will be redirected to the login page. This is working ok.

But for the newly created Area this is not working. The action can be called and the view will be returned which is not ok. I too decorated the controller with the Authorize attribute but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks
Sven

Comment: can you provide route config and controller header with attributes? Also please provide what you call and what you get.

Comment: please send code of new controller to find the problem

Comment: Sorry for late answer. It seems to work now, didn't change anything. Maybe I had a mistake in testing and forgot to log out. Thanks